# Windows forms Random Timed Math quiz c#

Tags: c#, winforms, windows-forms-designer

My problem is that I want to put a max number limit where the user would put a max question of 2 like an example and my program would show random question only 2 times but it keeps generating numbers I think my problem is with changing the textbox to int and where to place it I'm new to windows forms the first button generate random questions the second button should do the same but minus a number of question every time the user clicks I tried a lot `operationbox` is for the user to choose his operation(+,-,*,/) and the range box is the range of the random numbers.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace WindowsFormsApplication7
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            rangebox1.Items.Add("[1,100]");
            rangebox1.Items.Add("[1,500]");
            rangebox1.Items.Add("[1,1000]");
            Operationbox1.Items.Add("+");
            Operationbox1.Items.Add("-");
            Operationbox1.Items.Add("*");
            Operationbox1.Items.Add("/");
        }
      
        int[] Rand(int v)
        {

            Random r = new Random();
        int a = r.Next(1,v);
            int b = r.Next(1,v);
            int[] N = {Math.Max(a,b) , Math.Min(a,b)};
            return N;
        
        }
        void generate()
        {
            int range = 0;
            switch (rangebox1.SelectedIndex)
            { 
                case 0:
                    range = 100;
                    break;
                case 1:
                    range = 500;
                        break;
                case 2:
                    range = 1000;
                        break;
                default:
                    MessageBox.Show("Put a range !");
                    break;
            
            }
            int[] numbers = Rand(range);
            switch (Operationbox1.SelectedIndex)
            { 
                case 0:
                    questionlbl1.Text = string.Format("{0} + {1} =",numbers[0],numbers[1]);
                    break;
                case 1:
                    questionlbl1.Text = string.Format("{0} - {1} =" , numbers[0], numbers[1]);
                    break;
                case 2:
                    questionlbl1.Text = string.Format("{0} * {1} =" , numbers[0], numbers[1]);
                    break;
                case 3:
                    questionlbl1.Text = string.Format("{0} / {1} =" , numbers[0], numbers[1]);
                    break;
                default:
                    MessageBox.Show("Please insert a operation");
                    break;
            }
        
        }
        void numberquest()
        {
            int numofquestionleft = Convert.ToInt32(numofquest1.Text);
            int r = int.Parse(numofquest1.Text);
            if (numofquestionleft > 0) generate();
            numofquestionleft--;

        }

        private void genbutton1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            generate();
            
        }

      
        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            numberquest();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Please refine your question to a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) by removing unused methods, and by telling use what `rangebox1` and `Operationbox1` are. Also explain what “it's not working” means. Are you getting an error? Add the error message to your question.

Comment: sorry English is my second language but I edited my question I hope you can understand my problem now thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As far as I understood your question, you are facing issue with `numofquestionleft` variable and you want to restrict user to make max two number request. You need to modify your code. The way you are doing will not work. One solution could be,

Declare `numofquestionleft` as class level.

```
 public partial class Form1 : Form
{
   int numofquestionleft = 2; //here
    public Form1()
    {
```

And your `numberquest()` method would look like

```
 void numberquest()
    {
        
        if (numofquestionleft > 0)
           {
             generate();
           }
        numofquestionleft--;
        //You can use the textBox to communicate with user about number of turns left 
        //as
        numofquest1.Text ="Request left " +numofquestionleft;

    }
```

But if you still want to read max request from the textBox then the purpose of restricting users to make only two requests is lost (a user may enter some other number and you need to validate input in that case), moreover, you need to find a way to read data once.
Hope it helps.

Comment: Thank you it worked but yes I want the user to choose how many questions he wants I tried doing this but it keeps generating questions should I convert the text box somewhere else?                                                                                                                          void numberquest()
        {
            numofquestionleft = Convert.ToInt32(numofquest1.Text);

Comment: You need to shift this line of code, `int numofquestionleft = Convert.ToInt32(numofquest1.Text);` somewhere else. This is problematic. Everytime method is called `numofquestionleft` gets the initial value that is 2. And then in the method you do minus 1. As you call the method again, `numofquestionleft` assigned the value 2 again. Hope you understand. Put any other button like initialize the game and read data under the button event. Don't forget to declare the variable as class level because you need it available to the whole form.